# Would you implement a lightweight XML parser with <regex>?

Tags: c++, xml, regex, c++11

If you had to implement a lightweight XML parser, would you choose to use regex?

The XML parsing in my case would be most simplified: only tags and text content. No namespaces, no attributes, no schema support (at the beginning surely, but maybe...).

I think it would be a good exercise for me to learn the new C++0x <regex> library.
However, I was wondering if XML parsing wouldn't be above decent regex limits.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732454#1732454 (it's about XHTML, but I think it still somewhat applies. Also, it's awesome).

Comment: @SpaceCowboy Hmmm, that is **completely** related... ;-)

Comment: Bobince's answer is a great peace of absurd art. I Love this.

Comment: I meant **"great piece of Absurd art"** ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a word: no.  XML is not a regular language.

**UPDATE** *(To expand, based on the discussion in the comments below)*

XML is not regular, so you cannot hope to use regexes to perform some sort of one-hit parse/split operation on the entire file/string.

Whilst you could write a state-machine-based parser that uses regexes to perform the lexing/tokenisation, IMHO this would be less efficient, and more error-prone, than using a tool that's meant for the job.  As others have said, Flex/Bison is one option.

Comment: @Oli this is the definition of Regulare Language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language   What is the reason that makes XML a non regular language ?

Comment: @Stephane: For the same reason the language made of balanced pairs of parentheses is not regular (the star lemma). However, the answer is misleading, I doubt you'd write a huge regex for parsing a whole XML file.

Comment: This answer completely misses the point.  Regular expressions and (the sometimes surprisingly non-regular) regex are both used to parse non-regular languages — you just don't do it in a single expression.  You would, for example, use these expressions with most of the parser generators alluded to in the other answer.

Comment: @Roger, okay so you mean combine regex and lex/yacc/bison ?

Comment: @Stephane: Actually, combine `<regex>` and yacc/bison, or drop `<regex>` and use (f)lex. But if the exercise was to use C++0x, go with `<regex>` and write your own parser (XML was designed to be easy to parse).

Comment: @Roger: I'm aware that you can parse small enough bits of any language with regular expressions.  But what would be the point?  Yacc/Bison/etc. will do the job more efficiently and with less work.  Regular expressions are good for pattern-matching, etc.; they're not really the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Oli: Regular expressions are the canonical way to write parser rules.

Comment: @Roger: Yes, but that's not the same as saying that you'd use an actual regex library to do this.

Comment: @Oli: Try writing a recursive-descent parser by hand without some form of regular expression library.  The EDG C++ front-end, for example, is written this way — and it arguably has the best diagnostics in any widely-available compiler.

Comment: @Roger: I'll admit I've never written a non-trivial parser for anything other than learning/experimentation, and I did all the tokenisation state-machine code by hand.  For production code, I'd clearly never do this by hand, but I'd probably choose one of the aforementioned lexer/parser generators.  I guess the point I'm trying to make, occluded though it is, is that there are better, more-powerful tools out there.

Comment: @Oli: "All generalizations are false."  I can't say what I'd do for production code without knowing the requirements.  I guess the point I'm trying to make is "No, XML is not regular." is misleading and completely misses the point.

Answer (score 4):

If I had to do it, I'd use a real lexer/parser generator, like flex/yacc.  Yes, it's more work to get started, but once you pay that setup cost, adding support for additional features is much easier.  Also, flex and yacc have been optimized over the course of decades, so they'll generate much faster code than anything you'd write by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a lightweight XML parser and I did not use regex.
It's very easy to do if you only use a subset of XML. Just read the XML character by character, and update the status with a bunch of booleans (like in_a_tag). It's faster than anything you would do with regex, and you don't have to deal with the problem of lines or memory (try to match a line ? A whole document ? What if there are several elements on one line ? What if a tag is on 2 lines ?)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to parse XML: don't, get a real XML parser.

If you just want an exercise to get some experience with the new C++0x regex library: try to find a better and more useful project.  To start, you'd want something that has a chance of being used later (see above regarding a real XML parser).  That said, there are worse ways to learn a regex library. :)

Comment: Yes that's what I have been thinking of this afternoon. No bother with lex yacc for the moment. I'll use MSXML I am pretty used to now. And I'm gonna think of a simpler Interpreter Design Pattern using regex, but still don't know how/where, I'll figure that out later.