# Python split tags based on regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to split the following tag `<b size=5 alt=ref>` as follows:

```
Open tag: b
Parm: size=5
Parm: alt=ref
```

However, I tried the following code to split the tag as groups but it didn't work:

```
temp = '<b size=5 alt=ref>'
matchObj = re.search(r"(\S*)\s*(\S*)", temp)
print 'Open tag: ' + matchObj.groups()
```

My plan is to split the tag into groups and then print the first group as open tag and the rest as Parm. Can you please suggest any idea that helps me solving this problem?

Note that I read the tags from an html file but I mentioned here an example of open tag and I showed the part of the code that I am stuck with.

Thanks

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using an HTML parser?

Comment: If you [searched](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1GTPM_enUS601US601&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B%20parse%20xml%20using%20regex) you would find that [many people discourage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122624/would-you-implement-a-lightweight-xml-parser-with-regex) trying to parse XML/HTML/etc using regex, as there are already much more robust ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tag_names = ["Open tag:","Parm:","Parm:"]
import re  
# split on <,>,white space, and remove empty strings at
# the start and at the end of the resulting list. 
tags = re.split(r'[<> ]','<b size=5 alt=ref>')[1:-1]
# zip tag_names list and with list of tags
print(list(zip(tag_names, tags)))

[('Open tag:', 'b'), ('Parm:', 'size=5'), ('Parm:', 'alt=ref')]
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> temp = '<b size=5 alt=ref>'
>>> resList  = re.findall("\S+", temp.replace("<","").replace(">",""))
>>> myDict = {}
>>> myDict["Open tag:"] = [resList[0]]
>>> myDict["Parm:"] = resList[1:]
>>> myDict
{'Open tag:': ['b'], 'Parm:': ['size=5', 'alt=ref']}
```